# Selenium Wait for AJAX edit to text on page

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, webdriverwait

I have an element on a web page that is updated by AJAX almost immeditely after page load. I know what I expect the change to be and want Selenium to wait for the change and capture it. I am trying to use an explicit wait for this. However, I am getting a timeoutException as Selenium is not detecting the change.

I know I am properly selecting the element and value as I have used print statements. I've solved the issue using

`Java Thead.sleep(1000)`

and then using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("balance-sms")).getText()
```

but this is not an acceptable solution.

```
private void modalSend(String newBalence){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(modalSendButton)); //this wait works fine
        modalSendButton.click(); //this results in a page refresh
        //now check for the AJAX change to this element...normally takes about 1 second
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(driver.findElement(By.id("balance-sms")),newBalence));
        //continue...
    }
```

Comment: Code trials for _edit to text on page_? What error do you see?

Comment: timeoutException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the locator using `xpath` and `visibilityOfElementLocated` with a few modifications :

```
//now check for the AJAX change to this element...normally takes about 1 second
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='balance-sms' and contains(text(),'" +newBalence +"')]")));
//continue...
```

Comment: This solution worked for me although I don't understand it and never would have arrived here myself. The passing "and contains(text(),'" +newBalence +"')" makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with fluent wait like below instead of Thread.sleep

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(WebDriver reference)
.withTimeout(timeout, SECONDS)
.pollingEvery(timeout, SECONDS)
.ignoring(Exception.class);
```

Comment: Other than allowing me to set the polling time how is this different from using wait.until?